how to fix this error getting while making the init.lua file
I was following the video to setup my nevoim . So I was making the init.lua file but unable to make. Getting this error how to fix it as the person in the video didn't get this error . So how to fix it
 ~/.config/nvim/init.lua
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/pranshmaurya/.config/nvim/init.lua

I actually don't know how to fix this as I am new to nevoid

You first has to ensure the directory exists.
mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim/

Then you can create the file:
touch ~/.config/nvim/init.lua

(Or you can create it with an editor such as nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.lua)
